# How to configure Github "used by" feature for java projects

Tags: github

I have [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin) project hosted on Github:
[image: Fabric8 Maven Plugin]
Since this is a multi module project, it has got the main plugin in the plugins/ folder. If I go to insights and then dependency graph section I'm able to see correct count for the plugin usage(when I select plugin submodule):
[image: Dependency graph with submodules]

Does anyone know how to configure this `Used by` section on github to make it read plugins/ sub module rather than parent pom? Is there any feature like this available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** Dec 2022

As suggested by @armandino it is now possible to change the `Used by` section.

Please refer to the [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/exploring-the-dependencies-of-a-repository#changing-the-used-by-package) and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74790112/81444).

---

**[ORIGINAL Answer]**

It seems there is no way to configure the `Used by` section.

According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/angustweets/status/1134315377255522304), **currently** only the "alphabetically first package" in the repo get counted:

> For monorepos that include multiple packages the figure is
> misleading—it only represents dependents of the alphabetically first
> package. I'd love it if monorepo owners could at least choose which
> package to display "used by figures for".

Comment: Is there any update on this annoying issue?

Comment: @Gene there is. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74790112/45112

Answer (score 1):

You can now modify the **Used By** package through repository Settings as shown in the following screenshot from [Github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/exploring-the-dependencies-of-a-repository#changing-the-used-by-package).

[image]